# heimdallr if not set scope :delete

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I using a heimdallr for my models, and in the views use a `destroyable?` method, but I use destoy scope only for owners or admins, and when user not login `destroyable?` method raise Runtime error `The :delete scope does not exist`

How to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried creating a `:delete` scope or method on the model and setting it to something that doesn't return records?

It looks like this code is where it is failing:

https://github.com/roundlake/heimdallr/blob/master/lib/heimdallr/proxy/record.rb

```
def destroyable?
  scope = @restrictions.request_scope(:delete)
  record_in_scope? scope
end
```

So if your scope returns no records, it should in theory work just fine.

```
scope :delete, where(YourModel.arel_table[:id].lt(0))
```